# CSV output displays entire HTML page

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm trying to display only the files that I have found using the sql query but instead of printing those into a downloadable file, it's printing the entire html page along with it. I've been trying to put a

```
 break;
```

Somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

Here is my code:

```
   if(isset($generate))
            {

            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"generate_reports.csv\";" );
            header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

            $out = fopen("php://output", 'w');
            $flag = false;

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT location_name From locations");
                while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)))
                    {
                        if(!$flag)
                            {
                                $list = array("location_name"=>"location");
                                fputcsv($out, array_keys($list), ',', '"');
                                $flag = true;
                            }
                        fputcsv($out, array_values($row), ',', '"');
                    }
            fclose($out);
            }
```

**EDIT**

I've added the html codes that it's printing out:

```
    <h1>Generate Reports</h1>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="create" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Materials</strong></td>

<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db ("design_portal");
    $sql = "SELECT material_name FROM materials";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    echo "<td><select name='materials'>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['material_name'] . "'>" . 
            $row['material_name'] . "</option>";
        }

    echo "</select></td></tr> ";

    $sql2 = "SELECT location_name From locations";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

?>


                <td><strong>Locations</strong></td>
<?php

    echo "<td><select name='locations'>";
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) 
        {
            echo "<option value='" . $row2['location_name'] . "'>" . 
            $row2['location_name'] . "</option>";
        }   

    echo "</select></td></tr>";

?>
    <tr>
        <td><button name="submit" type=submit>Generate</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you include the entire file, including the HTML?

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP I have included the HTML

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that the `if(isset($generate))`-bit is only a small part of your entire file I advice you to put an `exit()` after the `fclose($out);`

`break` is only useful in loops or switches and will just execute the rest of the script. 
You actually want to terminate the script completely to prevent it doing that and  outputting the rest of the html.

Comment: This almost worked! It's still printing the <form> tags. I have updated my question to show the html.

Comment: Those are already outputted at the moment you are starting your CSV. It is important to know that php://output and the target of the echo are the same. You just need the php://output handle to be able to use the fputcsv function. Basically you need to modify your code to NOT do any echo before you past the code that generates the files.

Comment: So you're telling me that once I call the php://output, it automatically generates the entire page? Can you explain to me what the "w" means inside the parameters of fopen()?

Comment: As soon as you do an echo, it outputs to the users' browser. So anything you echo before you start calling fputcsv will appear in the window. Also, since your output has already started, the header calls won't have any effect. Both echo and fputcsv go directly to the users' browser is what I meant.